# Not all the methods in SharePoint Client Object Model can be access via REST API

Tags: jsom, client

I know there are two different ways of accessing the SharePoint data, Client Object Model and REST API. I am trying to get the count of the suspended workflow instances. The JSOM way works perfect for me,

```
workflowInstanceService.countInstances(subscriptionInstance);
```

but when I tried to call the this method via REST API, it tells me that the parameter 'parentSubscription' is not supported.
I was following this post to get the URL of REST API call, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292556.aspx

Could someone told me if there is a list of API references which could be accessed by REST HTTP call?